# android Cannot invoke substring(int, int) on the primitive type long

Tags: android, textview, substring

I have textview which will show large numbers and if the number of digits is larger than 5 I want to make the textview show only 4 digits with dots like this(3544...) I tried but I got this error:

android Cannot invoke substring(int, int) on the primitive type long

here is my code:

```
EditText EditNumber;
long  theNumber;

String str = EditNumber.getText().toString();

theNumber = Long.parseLong(str );

if( theNumber >5)
{
theNumber =  theNumber.substring(0,4)+"..."; // the error in this line.
textView1.setText(Long.toString(theSide));
}
else
{

 textView1.setText(Long.toString(theNumber));
 }
```

Comment: I don't get why you're parsing String to long and then back to String. What's the point of it? Leave it as String which is the object that has a `substring` method that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [Martin Cazares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965099/martin-cazares) the long does not have substring. Use your string instead of your double value.

```
EditText EditNumber;
long  theNumber;

String str = EditNumber.getText().toString();

if( str.length() > 4) // > 4 digits
{
    textView1.setText(str.substring(0,4)+"...");
}
else
{

     textView1.setText(str);
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that "long" do not have a substring method, be carefull with primitives, they do not have any methods at all...

If you want to substring do it like this:

```
String theNumber = str.substring(0,4)+"...";
textView1.setText(theNumber);
```

But beyond that, you might not even need to do it your self, look at the

> android:ellipsis="end" property of the TextView

it will do the ellipsis for you if the size of the TextView is smaller than the actual text.

Regards!

Comment: I tried it with integer and it gives me the same error>

Comment: you are not getting it, int/long/boolean/etc any primitive do not have methods, not even substring, you definitely need to read a java book before jumping into android to avoid these kind of issues...

Answer (score 0):

```
Long.toString(theNumber).substring(x,y);
```

That should give you the digits you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do a `substring` method call on a `Long` which doesn't have that method.  You probably intended to do `str.substring(0, 0)` instead.